Run Vertex AI notebook with user credential
I have a notebook in Vertex AI and I want to schedule it to run on a certain time of Day. My notebook makes a call to BigQuery to get data from certain tables and then process it. My challenge is the table the notebook calls has only my access and can't be given to the composer account. When I run the notebook manually it works but when I schedule it, it throws an error saying "Access Denied". How can I schedule my notebook with my access and not using a service account.
Tried to run notebook in BigQuery doesn't help.

you need to create a service account for your vertex ai notebook that has access to big query. Here is the guide. you need the bigquery.* access
in here.

I have a service account but I don't want to use service account as the table has PII data and service account can't be granted access. Only individual access is allowed.

but it is still possible to have read access when PII is enable. Here is a solution.

You should use Colab Enterprise Scheduler. (Not Workbench Scheduler)
https://cloud.google.com/colab/docs/schedule-notebook-run
This provides End User Credentials (EUC)
